# solve the following system of linear equation by substitution by first isolating $y$?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

**Here's what I was given:**

2$x$ + 3$y$ = 20

6$x$ - $y$ = 20

Firstly, in order to isolate $y$, I changed the second line so that $x$ would equal the equation and I got:

$x$ = $\frac{1}{6}$$y$ + $\frac{10}{3}$

In the first equation, I replaced $x$ with $\frac{1}{6}$$y$ + $\frac{10}{3}$ in order to solve for $y$:

2($\frac{1}{6}$$y$ + $\frac{10}{3}$) + 3$y$ = 20

$y$ is supposed to equal 4, and I didn't get 4.

**I don't understand what I got wrong?**

Comment: Nothing's wrong with what you've posted here. Try solving $2(\frac{1}{6}y+\frac{10}{3})+3y=20$ more carefully.

Comment: Try the last line again. 2(1/6 y + 10/3) + 3y = 20.

Comment: $2\left(\frac16 4+\frac{10}3\right)+3\cdot4=20$, so what ? You are not telling us the final part of your resolution, nor your final answer, which is where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Because you need isolate $y$, but you isolated $x$.

$y=6x-20$.

Thus, $2x+3(6x-20)=20$, which gives $x=4$, $y=4$ and we got the answer:
$$\{(4,4)\}.$$

Also, after your works you need to write $\frac{1}{3}y+\frac{20}{3}+3y=20$, which gives the same result:
$$y+20+9y=60$$ or
$$10y=40$$ or
$$y=4.$$

Comment: Mh, isolating the wrong unknown doesn't explain why the answer is [felt as] wrong, does it ?

Comment: @Yves Daoust See better  the header, please. It was typo. I fixed it. Thank you!